# Error Message during Exception .

Tags: c#

Hi  i have following method on my DataAccess Layer : 
Its fine but on Try Catch if there is error or SQL Exception i am logging it but it will return null to business logic layer in case of exception . But i want to handle it if there is error it should inform Business logic layer about error. Any idea how could i do that.

```
public DataTable  PapoulateIndexAnalyssList()
{
    DataTable dt;
    dt = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        this.indiceTableAdapter.FillBy(this.ds_IndexAnalysis.Indice);
        dt = this.tmp_Table_Analisi_IndexTableAdapter.GetData();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Logging Error:
        errorMessageVieReportDAL = ex.Message;
        Logs.WriteLog(errorMessageVieReportDAL);
        ObjResults.SetFailure = false;
        ObjResults.GetErrorMessage = errorMessageVieReportDAL;
    }
    return dt;
}
```

Comment: Why not just rethrow the exception?

Comment: Well Rethrow exception does not solve my problem because i am returning DataTable so imagine if there is exception it will not fill the dataTable and return null where my BAL object will also get null finally user have noting no values its ambiguous i want to show error message in case of Exception

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist on not rethrowing an exception you can always wrap your result in a response object.
The calling code would have to check if the result is in error state or not.
Your code would look something like this :

```
public QueryResult{
  public DataTable Data{get;set;}
  public bool Error{get;set;}
  public string ErrorMessage{get;set;}
}

public QueryResult PapoulateIndexAnalyssList()
{
    var result = new QueryResult();
    result.Data = new DataTable();
    try
    {
        this.indiceTableAdapter.FillBy(this.ds_IndexAnalysis.Indice);
        result.Data = this.tmp_Table_Analisi_IndexTableAdapter.GetData();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        //Logging Error:
        errorMessageVieReportDAL = ex.Message;
        Logs.WriteLog(errorMessageVieReportDAL);
        ObjResults.SetFailure = false;
        ObjResults.GetErrorMessage = errorMessageVieReportDAL;
        result.Error = true;
        result.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks all for your replies but i was looking for solution like Kristof has suggested me .

Answer (score 1):

You're instantiating the `DataTable` before the try/catch, so it won't be `null`, it'll be empty.

If you used this instead, then it would be `null`, if you feel that's enough information for the calling method to be able to determine that `PapoulateIndexAnalyssList` failed.

```
DataTable dt = null;
```

---

It's acceptable to act on the error (such as log it), but then rethrow it so that methods up the chain know about it too, and that's probably the correct way to handle this.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    //Logging Error:
    errorMessageVieReportDAL = ex.Message;
    Logs.WriteLog(errorMessageVieReportDAL);
    ObjResults.SetFailure = false;
    ObjResults.GetErrorMessage = errorMessageVieReportDAL;

    throw ex;
}
```

If the calling method needs to have an empty table, then that's the concern of the calling method, not `PapoulateIndexAnalyssList`. The calling method should handle that in its own `catch` block (in my opinion).

```
DataTable dt;

try
{
    dt = someClass.PapoulateIndexAnalyssList();
}
catch
{
    dt = new DataTable();
}
```

Comment: like svranken commented

Comment: @Kristof/Winney: Just asking whether he tried that. Could be that he doesn't want to just rethrow the exception (like in this example).

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't return `null` or `new DataTable()` if an error happens inside the data access layer, it will be ambiguous between no records found or an error happens. You need to rethrow the exception from the data access layer

```
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Logging Error:
    errorMessageVieReportDAL = ex.Message;
    Logs.WriteLog(errorMessageVieReportDAL);
    ObjResults.SetFailure = false;
    ObjResults.GetErrorMessage = errorMessageVieReportDAL;

    throw;
}
```

and catch the same exception in the presentation layer, then show some user friendly error message so user will be aware that an error happens.

Code in presentation layer:

```
DataTable dt = null;

try
{
    dt = BLL.PapoulateIndexAnalyssList();
}
catch
{
    // code to show user friendly error message here
}
```